# Chrome Bug Margin Auto

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a pretty weird issue that I can't replicate/ it's hard to debug.  Basically I center my header on the screen with

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1023px)
<style>
.NavBarMain_container__1eIjT {
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

When I click on on a different page it stays exactly as it is as it should.  My manager has the exact same chrome version and has gone into incognito as well and his is shifting by a couple pixels, but the layout tool in inspector is showing exactly the same things.  I can't really debug anything because I am seeing something different than him.

What would you recommend to do?  I think I can't use margin auto which is really strange.  I have never had an issue like this before:

```
Version 85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never solved why this is a bug but to get around it I used flex instead.  Flex relies on margin so not sure why it acts any different.   I did a bunch of screen shares and we had the same code when it was margin auto